# Appending to txt file produces strange characters

Tags: c#, text, encoding

My code is:

```
File.AppendAllText(
       @"C: \Users\aalig\Downloads\stok.txt", 
       "text content" + Environment.NewLine, 
       Encoding.UTF8);
```

But after the writing text file looks that - original text goes first correctly (expected), but followed by hieroglyphs instead of "text content":

[image: Image of invalid text]

Comment: Is this question incomplete? What error do you get? Please include more details to help others help you.

Comment: I have tried to write "text content" but it looks in text file "整瑸挠湯整瑮਍" @xmorera

Comment: Just as test, can you clear all file contents first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source file has different encoding (not UTF8 as code specifies). When `AppendAllText` adds text with UTF8 as requested it will append UTF8 encoded string. When such sequence of bytes read with another encoding (i.e. UTF16) it will be interpreted as different set of Unicode characters.

Two possible fixes :

1. use encoding of the file when appending text (if you know it)
2. read all text first and than re-write file with encoding of your choice.

Sample that produces **invalid** result:

```
string path = @"e:\temp\MyTest.txt";
File.WriteAllText(path, "Hello and Welcome" + Environment.NewLine, Encoding.Unicode);
// Note that AppendAllText uses different encoding than WriteAllText
// To correct - specify the same Encoding.Unicode (option 1)
File.AppendAllText(path, "text content" + Environment.NewLine, Encoding.UTF8);

Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(path));
```

results in

```
Hello and Welcome
整瑸挠湯整瑮਍
```

Sample that reads whole file and append your text (option 2)

```
File.WriteAllText(path, 
   File.ReadAllText(path) 
   + Environment.NewLine 
   + newContentToAdd);
```